# Google CLI Vertex AI commands

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Is there a possibility to schedule and run Vertex AI Workbench notebook instances via the CLI?
The [gcloud ai commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/create) enables custom-jobs, but only instant single time runs.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are looking for a solution to schedule only CLI commands to run vertex ai workbench notebook instances or not? Actually there are scheduling options available which do not involve CLI.

Comment: Yes, to integrate CI/CD into our deployment cycle, our team wants to be able to automate via the .gitlab-ci.yml file the scheduling of a notebook when it's pushed to master branch

Comment: Does this [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/scheduling-a-command-using-cloud-run-and-cloud-scheduler) by Google help you to solve your problem.Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a schedule run via Google Cloud console (Managed notebooks page)

[Schedule a managed notebooks run](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/schedule-managed-notebooks-run-quickstart)

Comment: Hi dannierl,
your link is not working but if you meant this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/schedule-managed-notebooks-run-quickstart) below, the content described here is exactly the thing we want to automate